# PHP Paypal MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON although JSON seems to be well formatted

Tags: php, json, paypal

I try to implement a paypal express checkout flow to a website.

The user must be able to adjust the order after they have logged in with paypal and choosed their payment option.

To do so, I create the order with paypal with the intent "AUTHORIZE" and user action "CONTINUE". It is created, the user is sent back to our website and I can fetch order and payer information with the (order) id created.

But then, when the payer is done checking and adjusting some final parameters and clicks the "buy now" button, I want to send the update order call as referenced here:
https://developer.paypal.com/api/orders/v2/#orders_patch

I create the payload in exactly the same way as for order creation, but this time with intent "CAPTURE" and user_action="PAY_NOW". I PATCH it to the correct path, but I keep getting the failure message "MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON" .

Hoewever, the JSON itself is a valid JSON, no errors thrown in creation. Here is a sample:

```
{
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "application_context": {
        "landing_page": "NO_PREFERENCE",
        "shipping_preference": "SET_PROVIDED_ADDRESS",
        "user_action": "PAY_NOW"
    },
    "purchase_units": [{
        "reference_id": "2289256",
        "description": "Your order at site",
        "custom_id": "order id 2289256",
        "soft_descriptor": "site name",
        "invoice_id": "2289256",
        "amount": {
            "currency_code": "EUR",
            "value": 59.98,
            "breakdown": {
                "item_total": {
                    "currency_code": "EUR",
                    "value": 50.41
                },
                "shipping": {
                    "currency_code": "EUR",
                    "value": 0
                },
                "discount": {
                    "currency_code": "EUR",
                    "value": 0
                },
                "tax_total": {
                    "currency_code": "EUR",
                    "value": 9.57
                }
            }
        },
        "items": [{
            "name": "Product 1",
            "description": "Product 1 Description",
            "sku": "1019879",
            "unit_amount": {
                "currency_code": "EUR",
                "value": 16.8
            },
            "tax": {
                "currency_code": "EUR",
                "value": 3.19
            },
            "quantity": "1",
            "category": "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
        }, {
            "name": "Product 2",
            "description": "Product 2 Description",
            "sku": "1024593",
            "unit_amount": {
                "currency_code": "EUR",
                "value": 33.61
            },
            "tax": {
                "currency_code": "EUR",
                "value": 6.38
            },
            "quantity": "1",
            "category": "PHYSICAL_GOODS"
        }],
        "shipping": {
            "name": {
                "full_name": "John Doe"
            },
            "address": {
                "address_line_1": "Badensche Str. 24",
                "address_line_2": "",
                "admin_area_2": "Berlin(Berlin)",
                "postal_code": "10715",
                "country_code": "DE"
            }
        }
    }]
}
```

Here is paypal´s response

```
{
    name: "INVALID_REQUEST",
    message: "Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.",
    debug_id: "c315ce9eb90b4",
    details: [{
        field: "/",
        location: "body",
        issue: "MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON",
        description: "The request JSON is not well formed.",
    }],
    links: [{
        href: "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-MALFORMED_REQUEST_JSON",
        rel: "information_link",
        encType: "application/json",
    }],
}
```

I just cannot figure out the problem. I tried to remove the whole application_context, purchase_units, intent and see if there is a problem within any of these parameters. Nothing changed. What exactly is wrong with this call?

Answer (score 1):

That's not how a patch operation works. A patch operation's JSON payload must look something like the example in the API reference:

```
'[
  {
    "op": "replace",
    "path": "/purchase_units/@reference_id==\'default\'/shipping/address",
    "value": {
      "address_line_1": "123 Townsend St",
      "address_line_2": "Floor 6",
      "admin_area_2": "San Francisco",
      "admin_area_1": "CA",
      "postal_code": "94107",
      "country_code": "US"
    }
  }
]'
```

However, based on the information provided it's unclear why you are attempting to use a PATCH, since you do not list any relevant fields for a patch.

Intent authorize and intent capture are for creating an order. Use one or the other, never both for the same transaction. To capture an order that was created with intent capture, use a capture API call. To authorize an order that was created with intent authorize, use an authorize API call. The relevant API endpoints for either will be in the API response when you create the order, or you can read the documentation.

Since it appears your intended result is a captured payment (rather than an authorization), intent authorize is not relevant to your use case.

Comment: ooooh, ok. Thank you. This whole thing about "PATCH" is new to me. Since the params list also included "intent" I thought this would end up in sending the orders payload with adjustments again... Would you know about a more detailed example to patch the whole order (also positions and values?)  Could the path be just ""/purchase_units/@reference_id=='default'/" then and then use the whole body as above?